# sql query to avg over a fixed range over the entire data set

Tags: mysql

I have a sql table like this:

| date | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 12-22-2022 | 23 |
| 12-21-2022 | 26 |
| 12-20-2022 | 27 |
| 12-19-2022 | 25 |
| 12-18-2022 | 26 |
| 12-17-2022 | 27 |
| 12-16-2022 | 29 |
| 12-15-2022 | 28 |
| 12-14-2022 | 29 |
| 12-13-2022 | 30 |
| 12-12-2022 | 27 |
| 12-11-2022 | 29 |
| 12-10-2022 | 29 |
| 12-09-2022 | 28 |
| 12-08-2022 | 31 |
| 12-07-2022 | 32 |
| 12-06-2022 | 33 |
| 12-05-2022 | 34 |
| 12-04-2022 | 33 |
| 12-03-2022 | 32 |
| 12-02-2022 | 29 |
| 12-01-2022 | 33 |
| 11-30-2022 | 31 |
| 11-29-2022 | 33 |
| 11-28-2022 | 32 |

I want to write a query that would give me an average of 7 day chunks ending in the latest day.

| week_ending_in_date | avg_temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 12-22-2022 | 26.1428 |
| 12-15-2022 | 28.5714 |
| 12-08-2022 | 32.0000 |
| 12-01-2022 | 32.2500 |

The last row is the average of 4 days ending in 12-01-2022 (i.e. 33,31,33,32)

This query is meant to run daily - so the week_ending_in_date will also change daily.
How should I approach this with a sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem following these steps:

- convert the format of your "*date*" field from `VARCHAR` to `DATE`
- generate your partitions on your dates for each 7 days
- aggregate for each partition, by getting the maximum date and the average temperature

In order to generate your partition, you use:

- the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) window function, if your date values are always consecutives (every day a new temperature will appear)
- the [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function, to normalize the date to actual weeks, if your date values are not always consecutives (you forget to record temperature values some days)

**First Solution** ([fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4mcanHgo8rrj6KLPTs24mm/1)):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date_, '%m-%d-%Y') AS date_as_date,  
           temperature 
    FROM tab
), partitioned_dates AS (
    SELECT *, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date_as_date DESC) -1) DIV 7 AS rn
    FROM cte
)
SELECT MAX(date_as_date) AS week_ending_in_date,
       AVG(temperature)  AS avg_temperature
FROM partitioned_dates
GROUP BY rn
```

**Second Solution** ([fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4mcanHgo8rrj6KLPTs24mm/0)):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date_, '%m-%d-%Y')                 AS date_as_date,
           UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(date_, '%m-%d-%Y')) AS integer_date,  
           temperature 
    FROM tab
), partitioned_dates AS (
    SELECT *, (MAX(integer_date) OVER(ORDER BY integer_date DESC) - integer_date) DIV (60*60*24*7) AS rn
    FROM cte
)
SELECT MAX(date_as_date) AS week_ending_in_date,
       AVG(temperature)  AS avg_temperature
FROM partitioned_dates
GROUP BY rn
```

**Extra tips**:

- Use MySQL standard for dates: you're storing in the `%mm-%dd-%yyyy` format, [MySQL standard for dates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) is `%dd-%mm-%yyyy`.
- Don't store dates as `VARCHAR`. MySQL has the `DATE` datetype, that allows you to use a wide [toolkit of functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) at your disposal.
- Don't use names that match [reserved MySQL keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) to name your tables and fields. Specifically, the "*date*" field name can conflict with the `DATE` reserved word for its homonimous datatype, you may run into syntax errors.

Following MySQL rules will considerably help you with manipulation and save yourself a lot of time.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed and thorough answer!